# Firebase Crashlytics Bitmap OutOfMemoryError which activity

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, bitmapfactory

I see a user of mine got a crash. How do I know when this crash happened? Which activity did it happen in? Which line of code?

I don't use Bitmap factory anywhere, but I do display some pictures in ImageView.

Here is the crash as shown to me in the Firebase console:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreateFromParcel(Bitmap.java)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.access$000(Bitmap.java:31)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap$1.createFromParcel(Bitmap.java:1308)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap$1.createFromParcel(Bitmap.java:1300)
   at android.app.IUiAutomationConnection$Stub$Proxy.takeScreenshot(IUiAutomationConnection.java:224)
   at android.app.UiAutomation.takeScreenshot(UiAutomation.java:599)
   at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.platform.common.Utils.takeScreenshot(Utils.java:42)
   at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.platform.hybrid.ViewScreenStateBuilder.traverseAndBuild(ViewScreenStateBuilder.java:41)
   at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridStateExtractor.tryExtractingScreenState(HybridStateExtractor.java:40)
   at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridStateExtractor.getStableScreen(HybridStateExtractor.java:8)
   at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform.handlePerformScrape(RemotePlatform.java:40)
   at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform.access$400(RemotePlatform.java:81)
   at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform$ControllerMessageHandler.handleMessage(RemotePlatform.java:10)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I never got this crash myself? I can see which device it happened on, (Galaxy S3), so I tried it in an emulator, and everything worked.

Thanks

Here is screen shot from email
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is coming from a user.  The origin of your stack trace is `com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler`.  This is most likely coming from the [Goole Play Pre-launch Test Report](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/pre-launch-crash-reports) when you submitted your *.apk to Google Play.  This happens automatically.  And as one of the the other comments stated, it looks like it's running out of memory when the crawler is taking a screenshot.

If you log into Google Play, you should see an option to view the Prelaunch test report (from the left menu go to `Release Management -> Pre-launch report`).  In fact, you should have gotten a warning right before you published the app I believe.  This is probably a bug in that service and not a user.  So you probably don't have to worry about it.  Though it might be a good idea to file a bug Google Play.

Comment: Thanks a million. This was it.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to load the full Bitmap and are running out of memory.

Review the Android Developers article for efficiently loading bitmaps:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Comment: I have no bitmaps in my app!

Comment: It looks like the crux of it is the user is taking a screenshot

Comment: hmmm. thats interesting.

Answer (score 0):

if you connected with your email, you will always get an email from firebase

**like this**  [image]

Comment: I attached a picture, it still doesn't tell me which line of code caused it

Comment: is your firebase connected with your email?

Comment: Yes, I attached the email that i got. Thanks